# Laravel Custom Form With Multiple Color

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am using laravel form to insert multiple colors using from input type as color,

```
{{ Form::input('color','color[]',null, array('class' => 'form-control-color','placeholder' => 'Enter Color','id' => 'exampleInputTitle1')) }}
```

But i am getting this error, "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", Can any one have an idea to how to handle the Color input field as multiple values.

Comment: Are you trying to add it as a dropdown list? The second parameter is usually for the default value for text input and selectable values for select dropdown input.

Comment: May be a useful link for you: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/161/creating-a-form-input-field

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of this, but if you try:

```
{{ Form::input('color','color[0]',null, array('class' => 'form-control-color','placeholder' => 'Enter Color','id' => 'exampleInputTitle1')) }}
```

Does it work?

Comment: Great, don't forget to increment the index when adding a new field.